# Word 2010: Make objects span across two pages in a booklet

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word 2010 (and also other versions), one can make a booklet easily by selecting Book fold in Page Setup. [Click for a screenshot if you have no idea what I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfoJU.png)

Here's the editing in Word:

[image: A screenshot of Word]

So on the second page there is a text box which I want it to span across two pages. It seems fine if I have ≦4 pages.

[image: 4-page booklet]

**But it doesn't work with more pages.**

[image: 8-page booklet]

As shown in the screenshot, the extended part is printed on the 7<sup>th</sup> page, which is obviously **not** what I want.

Also, the "effect" cannot be seen in Word itself (you can't see the other half of the object on page 3), but it is included in printing. I wonder if this is a bug. (In this case I am using PDFCreator to prevent wasting paper.)

How can I do that easily and correctly?